# Broken bar diagram with tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I am trying out tikz package to create bar diagrams and following the code example in the manual on page 84 http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=84

gives me a broken bar diagram.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}
 [
  ybar,
  enlargelimits=0.15,
  legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
  anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
  ylabel={Anzahl der täglich hochgeladenen Fotos (in Millionen)},
  symbolic x coords={2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014},
  xtick=data,
  nodes near coords,
  nodes near coords align={vertical},
 ]
 \addplot coordinates {(2008,17) (2008,0) (2008,0) (2008,0)};
 \addplot coordinates {(2009,69) (2009,0) (2009,0) (2009,0)};
 \addplot coordinates {(2010,197) (2010,0) (2010,0) (2010,0)};
 \addplot coordinates {(2011,249) (2011,9) (2011,0) (2011,0)};
 \addplot coordinates {(2012,300) (2012,9) (2012,51) (2012,0)};
 \addplot coordinates {(2013,343) (2013,51) (2013,394) (2013,394)};
 \addplot coordinates {(2014,351) (2014,60) (2014,703) (2014,703)};
\legend{Facebook,Instagram,Snapchat,WhatsApp}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

the concrete problems are:

- the bars are not shown correctly
- the values are either out of bound or mixed together
- the bar diagram is generally too small (how do I specify `\linewidth`?)

Comment: Why are you insert a lot of equal coordinates: `(2009,69) (2009,0) (2009,0) (2009,0)`? The last 3 are equal.

Comment: my symbolic x coords are years so if I did not misunderstood the manual I have to write the y coords for each corresponding x coord. in that case some data where not available for that year thus 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note, that the first `\addplotplot` draws the graph for the first label, i.e. your first `\addplot`comment should contain all Facebook coordinates. So I think you have to change the assignment of the `coordinates` to the `\addplot` commands. Additionally I change the `width` of the `axis`, the `bar width` and `enlargelimits` and set the `compat` to the current version 3.12.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}% current version

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=\linewidth,
    ybar,
    bar width=8pt,
    ymin=0,
    enlarge x limits={abs=25pt},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Anzahl der täglich hochgeladenen Fotos (in Millionen)},
    symbolic x coords={2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west,font=\footnotesize},
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {% Facebook
    (2008,17) (2009,69) (2010,197) (2011,249) (2012,300) (2013,343) (2014,351)};
  \addplot coordinates {% Instagram
    (2008,0) (2009,0) (2010,0) (2011,9) (2012,9) (2013,51) (2014,60)};
  \addplot coordinates {% Snapshot
    (2008,0) (2009,0) (2010,0) (2011,0) (2012,51) (2013,394) (2014,703)};
  \addplot coordinates {% WhatsApp
    (2008,0) (2009,0) (2010,0) (2011,0) (2012,0) (2013,394) (2014,703)};
  \legend{Facebook,Instagram,Snapchat,WhatsApp}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Update:** Of course you can also a text file like

```
Year, Facebook, Instagram, Snapchat, WhatsApp
2008, 17, 0,0,0 
2009,69,0,0,0
2010,197,0,0,0
2011,249,9,0,0
2012,300,9,51,0
2013,343,51,394,394
2014,351,60,703,703
```

Then you have to use

```
\addplot table[col sep=comma,x=Year,y=Facebook]{<filename>};
\addplot table[col sep=comma,x=Year,y=Instagram]{<filename>};
\addplot table[col sep=comma,x=Year,y=Snapchat]{<filename>};
\addplot table[col sep=comma,x=Year,y=WhatsApp]{<filename>};
```

Or you use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` to plot more than one column from a file:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data\jobname.csv}
Year, Facebook, Instagram, Snapchat, WhatsApp
2008, 17, 0,0,0 
2009,69,0,0,0
2010,197,0,0,0
2011,249,9,0,0
2012,300,9,51,0
2013,343,51,394,394
2014,351,60,703,703
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}% current version

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=\linewidth,
    ybar,
    bar width=8pt,
    ymin=0,
    enlarge x limits={abs=25pt},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Anzahl der täglich hochgeladenen Fotos (in Millionen)},
    symbolic x coords={2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west,font=\footnotesize},
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
  ]
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{Facebook,Instagram,Snapchat,WhatsApp}{
    \addplot table[col sep=comma,x=Year,y=#1]{data\jobname.csv};
    \addlegendentry{#1}
  }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: workfs perfect. thanks. One additional thing.. how do I specify the usage of a csv file where the date is in this format:
Year, Facebook, Intagram, Snapchat, Whatsapp
2008, 17, 0,0,0
2009, 123,31,123,123

and so on. I get this `\addplot table[x=Jahr, y=Summe] {data2.csv};` command but I "more" x and y values. is there a way?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: sorry but just one final question then I am satisfied. :)

I defined these colors:

\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,150,214}
\definecolor{greenaccent}{RGB}{0,139,43}
\definecolor{purpleaccent}{RGB}{130,41,128}
\definecolor{orangeaccent}{RGB}{240,83,50}


how do I get them into my graph? facebook would be blue, instagram green and so on. `\addplot[fill=blue]` colors all bars, so I would need something like: y#1fill=blue