# Use separate colors for a multi-bar diagram plotted from file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Based on my origin question here: [Broken bar diagram with tikz package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248243/broken-bar-diagram-with-tikz-package/248284?noredirect=1#comment590795_248284)

I am trying to color each single of a group differently. In my preamble I have defined the colors I want to use:

```
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,150,214}
\definecolor{greenaccent}{RGB}{0,139,43}
\definecolor{purpleaccent}{RGB}{130,41,128}
\definecolor{orangeaccent}{RGB}{240,83,50}
```

and `pgfplots` is loaded right after `xcolor`.
At the moment my code looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        width=\linewidth,
        ybar,
        bar width=7.5pt,
        ymin=0,
        enlarge x limits={abs=25pt},
        legend style={draw=none,at={(0.5,-0.15)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
        xlabel={Jahre},
        ylabel={Fotos pro Tag (in Millionen)},
        symbolic x coords={2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014},
        xtick=data,
      ]
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{Facebook,Instagram,Snapchat,WhatsApp}{
        \addplot[
            draw opacity=0,
            fill=blue
        ] table[col sep=semicolon,x=Jahr,y=#1]{./Bilder/AnzahlSocialNetwork.csv};
        \addlegendentry{#1}
        }
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Anzahl der täglich hochgeladenen Fotos (in Millionen)}
    \label{fig:AnzahlTäglichFotosSocialNetwork}
\end{figure}
```

but the fill option inside `\addplot` colors everything blue (obviously). What I need is something where I can define the first y graph to be blue, the second one green, third purple, and last orange as per defined colors. In the manual it was written that one can use the bar cycle list but I could not find a option where I can use RGB values like defined here (instead of percentage of a color).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it to a `cycle list` key however you need to put a `+` sign after the `\addplot` command to make it understand as `/.append style` as opposed to overwriting `/.style` to use the `cycle list` argument. You can turn off the  drawing with `draw=none`.

And please don't overwrite existing color names for your own sake :)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
Year, Facebook, Instagram, Snapchat, WhatsApp
2008, 17, 0,0,0
2009,69,0,0,0
2010,197,0,0,0
2011,249,9,0,0
2012,300,9,51,0
2013,343,51,394,394
2014,351,60,703,703
}\mytable

\definecolor{blueaccent}{RGB}{0,150,214}
\definecolor{greenaccent}{RGB}{0,139,43}
\definecolor{purpleaccent}{RGB}{130,41,128}
\definecolor{orangeaccent}{RGB}{240,83,50}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=\linewidth,
    ybar,
    bar width=7.5pt,
    ymin=0,
    enlarge x limits={abs=25pt},
    legend style={draw=none,at={(0.5,-0.15)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    xlabel={Jahre},
    ylabel={Fotos pro Tag (in Millionen)},
    symbolic x coords={2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014},
    xtick=data,
    cycle list={blueaccent,greenaccent,purpleaccent,orangeaccent}
  ]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{Facebook,Instagram,Snapchat,WhatsApp}{
      \addplot+[draw=none,fill,] table[x=Year,y=#1]{\mytable};
      \addlegendentry{#1}
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: draw=none is the border/edge around each bar in a darker color of the same color right? I read in another answer that draw opacity = 0 would do that but either way it works so I am happy. Thanks